# What does AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0xffffffffffffffbe mean?

Tags: c, string, runtime-error

I'm getting an error in the code and I don't know what it means, this is the first time I've come across it.

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0xffffffffffffffbe (pc 0x7f3dfc3c588c bp 0x7ffe82c73070 sp 0x7ffe82c727d0 T0)
==30==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x7f3dfc3c588b  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0xd688b)
    #3 0x7f3dfb7b70b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0xd688b) 
==30==ABORTING
```

I need to reverse every words in a line.I think it occurs in the second cycle. my idea is to find the first and last  index of each words. This is my code:

```
char * reverseWords(char * s){
    int n = strlen(s);
char *res = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
int firstI, lastI;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    firstI = i;
    while (++i < n && strcmp(res[i], ' ') == 0){
        lastI = i - 1;
    }
    while (firstI > lastI){
        char temp = res[firstI];
        res[firstI++] =  res[lastI];
        res[lastI--] = temp;
    }
}
return res;
}
```

new code

```
char * reverseWords(char * s){
    int n = strlen(s);
char *res = malloc(n + 1);
strcpy(res, s);
int firstI, lastI;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    firstI = i;
    while (++i < n && res[i] == ' '){
        lastI = i - 1;
    }
    while (firstI > lastI){
        char temp = res[firstI];
        res[firstI++] =  res[lastI];
        res[lastI--] = temp;
    }
}
return res;
}
```

Comment: It probably means you managed to subtract a smallish number (0x32) from a null  pointer and then dereferenced it.  That would probably be a pointer that's supposed to be an array of a structure type indexed by `-1`.

Comment: No need to use `sizeof(char)`. It is, by _definition_ always 1, regardless of the number of bits in a `char`. Change `malloc(sizeof(char) * n)` into `malloc(n + 1)`. The +1 provides space for the 0x00 string terminator char. Also, at the end, you need to add that terminator to `res`

Comment: Also, `strcmp(res[i], ' ') == 0` is wrong. It won't even compile cleanly (with warnings enabled via `-Wall`) because `res[i]` generates the _character_ value and _not_ a `char *` (which is what `strcmp` needs). This will almost certainly segfault. Change to: `res[i] == 0`

Answer (score 1):

**Off by one error:**

```
int n = strlen(s);
char *res = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
```

`strlen()` does not count the terminating null-byte. You did not allocate space for it.

---

**Lack of null-terminator:**

```
return res;
```

You do not null-terminate `res` before returning.

---

**strcmp() compares strings:**

```
strcmp(res[i], ' ')
```

The arguments to `strcmp()` must be `char *`s, not `char`s.

---

Aside: Code risks undefined behavior if `malloc()` returned `NULL`.

---

Edit: Current code is too complicated. I simplified things and added some checks.

```
  static char *reverseWords(char *str)
  {
      /* NULL pointer. */
      if (!str) {
          return 0;
      }
      /* Empty string. */
      if (*str == '\0') {
          return 0;
      }
      /* Assuming it's null-terminated. */
      char *src = str;
      char *dest = src + (strlen(str) - 1); /* -1 for the null-byte. */
 
      /* ++ and -- have higher precedence than the * operator.
      *  But, in an expression, they return the old value of their
      *  operand. So this copies first, then increments the pointer
      *  point to the next char.
      */
      while (src < dest) {
          char tmp = *src;
          *src++ = *dest;
          *dest-- = tmp;
      }
      return str;
  }
```

**Sample I/O:**

```
 Input: Hello
 Output: olleH
```

Comment: i change the code but my bproblem didn't  go away

Comment: @ДенисМороз And what exact changes did you make?

Comment: I copied the input string into a new one along with null termination

Comment: But this code still doesn't work correctly i think the problem is in (res[i] == ' ') in the output i get unmodified string

Comment: Kindly explain what you mean by '*This code doesn't work"*. I was unable to understand what *"I get the unmodified string*" mean. How are you calling your code? Where's the `main()` function? Does the program still crash?

Comment: This task with LeetCode I do not have access to the main() function. In the reverseWords() function I have to change the string and return it but when I run the code in the output I get the unchanged input string